# Custom Buttons looking bad in application now that we've upgraded Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been working on my application for a while in Android 2.2, and I'm pretty happy with it.  However, technology advances and it's time to upgrade the old girl to work with Honeycomb and ICS...

One of the things that's not looking right is the buttons on my screen.  It's frustrating, but I can't seem to find a way to make them look the way they used to.  My buttons use a custom drawable, which is an XML file, not an actual graphic.  It looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#444444"
                android:endColor="#444444" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:antialias="true" 
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners
                android:radius="8dip" />

            <padding
                android:left="2dip"
                android:top="2dip"
                android:right="2dip"
                android:bottom="2dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The buttons grab this code in the layout.xml file like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/def_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

This used to produce a nice, professional-looking rounded-corner rectangle button with a white border and a gray center.  However, now that I'm running my code on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (running ICS) the rounded parts of the border are not white -- they're gray, and it looks bad.  I have discovered the corners will be white if I fatten up the stroke to 2dip, but I really would prefer to preserve the earlier version look of the software.

I've learned from experience that if I were drawing something with curves with a Paint & Canvas, the answer to this problem is to ensure that anti-aliasing is on.  However, even though there IS an android:antialias key for XML (you can see it in the  section -- but it doesn't work), I can't figure out how to use it.

Does anyone have any suggestions??

Thanks,
R.

Comment: You deleted the question before I could answer... can you undelete it, please? at least to let me post an answer, to show you the error in your layout. The one with the swapped Views.

Comment: The one in which you say: `The inverted items are ViewSpaceA and ViewSpaceB` ... Or did you find the answer yourself?

Comment: I'm going to close, for today. Reply me here if you want an answer to that question (also to inform me if you eventually undeleted it). This is the question address, just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394409/android-layout-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I could find was to grow the size of the white outline from 1dp to 2dp.
The reason I can think of that this would work is color-aliasing for the curved line, but I was unsuccessful at addressing the issue directly.  At first, it really wasn't the look I was going for, but it's grown on me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this could simply be the screen quality. Alternatively, it could be aliasing between the border and the centre.

This code may get around the aliasing:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#444444"
                android:startColor="#444444" />

            <corners android:radius="8dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>

            <stroke
                android:antialias="true"
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="8dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like your first sentence may be correct -- It may just be the screen.  The file you gave me produces exactly the same results as my original, but thanks anyway for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 9 patch drawable which won't have this anti-aliased look to it.